# Includes with two projects

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

So in visual studio I have a solution with two projects in it.

One compiles as a dynamic lib and is used as a reference for the other one, the executable.

The dll one uses some external dependencies.

My problem is that when I include the dependency header file:

```
#include <dependency.h>
```

the second project complains that the file doesn't exist.

When I include it like this though

```
#include "../../../depedency.h"
```

it works fine. How can I fix this issue without setting up include directories for my second project?

Comment: Why would anyone try to link 2 different projects? A project is supposed to be seperate from each other. When you have something related, put in one single project

Comment: ***How can I fix this issue without setting up include directories for my second project?*** Modify your project settings not your includes. Or is this what you are trying to avoid??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put a relative include like this `#include "../../../depedency.h"` you need to assure that this path is actually true for all files that include a header with such dependency.

To solve this issue you could simply switch back to the `#include <dependency.h>` option and update your projects settings. How to do this slightly depends on your VS version. For VS2015 for both project you should go to **Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General** and in the **Additional Include Directories** set the path to where your `dependency.h` resides.

Remember the settings should be applied for Debug/Release configurations and the Platforms you require.

Comment: Then please give a general structure of the project - where the project files are, where the `dependency.h` lies and what Additional Includes where set for the project that won't see the header

Comment: So there are two different projects in the same solution. One uses the other as a reference which compiles as a dll. That dll uses some additional dependencies. I have set the include directories under the vc++ directories tab. The dependency header is included in one of the files of the dll project which compiles just fine. But when I try to compile the other project I get a c1083 error that the dependency header is not found but for the second project.

Comment: ***I get the same error.*** You must have not put the correct path in your Additional Includes.

Comment: Regarding structure I meant the dirs and subdirs layout to verify whether proper paths were set in additional includes because it sounds like there's still a problem with that

Comment: The paths are correct since the functions and everything work perfectly. It only gives me an error when I try to compile.

Comment: What do you mean by *works perfectly* when the project doesn't compile? The dll might compile fine but the project which uses it and includes the problematic header doesn't. Seems like paths issue that's why I'm asking for structure details and exact entry from additional includes

Comment: ***It only gives me an error when I try to compile.*** That means you still have not entered the correct include path for `dependency.h` in your additional includes for the second project.

Comment: If `#include "../../../depedency.h"` works perhaps adding `../../../` to your additional includes for the second project would fix the problem.

Comment: Any results with what @drescherjm proposed?

Comment: That did work, but is there any way not to use additional include directories in the second project, except the header from the first one?

Comment: I don't think there is a way around setting the path if the include is really needed. If you can eliminate the need for the include (perhaps a forward reference  or using PIMPL) however then you may not need the path. This is hard to answer because we know very little about the code.

Comment: Okay so I have to do the same for the additional libraries?

Comment: You can try doing what @drescherjm suggested - use the PIMPL idiom and forward declarations to try hiding the needed details on the library side. You can read some usefull info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028104/pimpl-idiom-vs-forward-declaration) and [here](http://wiki.c2.com/?PimplIdiom)